# How to get horizontal Scrollview with images like in Apple watch Music App

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have tried some ways to get the view as Apple watch music App,Still couldn't be able to get like this(Please check the attached image).Simply I want to have a scrolling features in Apple watch to show set of images and its details.
Please advice me regarding this,Thanks

[image: Screen shot of Apple watch music App]

Answer (score 0):

You can use flow layout with horizontal scrolling

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
...
layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: Yes, you can see the dump-class headers of WatchOS here https://github.com/nickfrey/WatchOS-Headers/blob/master/Device/NanoPassKitUI.framework/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout-Protocol.h